# How to use URI's with an imageAdapter

Tags: android

I have an ArrayList of Uri's that i want to display in a ViewPager,

**this is how my code looks, I have both shown how i have put the URi into a bitmap and a drawable:**

```
public class ImageViewActivity extends Activity {

private List<String> selectedItems;
private Uri uri1;
private Drawable drawable1;
private Bitmap bitmap1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_view);
    ExtendedViewPager mViewPager = (ExtendedViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new TouchImageAdapter());

    selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    selectedItems = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("selectedItems");
    Log.d(ImageViewActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "" + selectedItems.get(0));

    uri1 = Uri.parse( selectedItems.get(0));

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri1);
        drawable1 = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, uri1.toString());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        drawable1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url);
    }


    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedItems.get(0));

    bitmap1 = myBitmap;


}
static class TouchImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private static int[] images = {};
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }
    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(container.getContext());
        img.setImageResource(images[position]);
        container.addView(img, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        return img;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

}

**but the refference code i'm looking at, has it in the "Drawable Resource Folder", code looks like this:**

```
public class ViewPagerExampleActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewpager_example);
    ExtendedViewPager mViewPager = (ExtendedViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new TouchImageAdapter());
}

static class TouchImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private static int[] images = { R.drawable.nature_1, R.drawable.nature_2, R.drawable.nature_3, R.drawable.nature_4, R.drawable.nature_5 };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(container.getContext());
        img.setImageResource(images[position]);
        container.addView(img, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        return img;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

}
```

}

I want to use each of my URI's in the ImageAdapter, i just can't figure out how to "put them into" the ImageAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all get the absolute path of image from Uri Because we can not convert image into bitmap using image Uri ,so just with the help of following code you can get  Absolute path

```
  Uri ImageURI = "your image uri goes here";    
  String   selectedImagePath = ImageFilePath.getPath(getApplicationContext(), ImageURI);

  File imageFile =   new File(selectedImagePath);
  Bitmap bitmap  =   BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

then set image bitmap in the ImageView

```
imageView.setImageBitmap (bitmap);
```

hopefully this will solve your problem.